# SqlAlchemy in_ opeator with NULL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I would like to use the in_ operator in sqlalchemy using two values, one of them being NULL (mysql NULL), I don't know how to pass it via Python?

So I have a Python cgi that contains a bunch of parameters that I format then finally store inside a dict `queryValues` (the key being the column name and the value being a value sent by the user stored inside a fieldStorage)

```
for attr,value in queryValues.items() :  #queryValues is a dict of parameters
     valueWithNone = value.append(None) #I want to includ NULL
     and_args_of_cr = [(and_(getattr(TableCR.c,attr).in_(valueWithNone)))]
```

I tried None and `sqlalchemy.sql.null()`, also tried putting directly `in_(value,None)` but value has the form `['Yes']` so I don't know how to do this.

But it's not working, how can I do this please?

Answer (score 1):

The line `value.append(None)` is an in-place modification and does not return anything, so `valueWithNone` will be None. This is probably what you're after:

```
for attr,value in queryValues.items():
    queryvalues = value[:]  # Create a copy of list
    queryvalues.append(None)
    and_args_of_cr = [(and_(getattr(TableCR.c,attr).in_(queryvalues)))]
```